# Derivative of Hankel functions and Bessel functions

Tags: special-functions

Dose anyone know about the formulations of derivative of Bessel and Hankel function as below, because when I just used the derivative of Bessel function and Hankel function as in the following references

1. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/bessel/bessel_derivatives.html
2. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Derivative of Bessel function:
\begin{align}
\text{J}_n^{\prime}(z) &= -\text{J}_{n+1}(z) + \frac{n}{2}\text{J}_n(z).
\end{align}
Derivative of Hankel function:
\begin{align}
\text{H}_n^{(2)\prime}(z) &= -\text{H}_{n+1}^{(2)\prime}(z) + \frac{n}{2}\text{H}_n^{(2)\prime}(z).
\end{align}
Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking if the displayed formulas are correct?  Or for a proof?  Or for a reference on the subject?  Do you know about https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6#i ?